# SQL NOT LIKE Wildcard Condition on Inner Join

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table called hr_grades that contains employee pay grades such as:-

```
ID  hr_grade  
1   PR07
2   AC04
```

I run two stored procedures. One that returns employees whose grades are in this table, and one that does not. These stored procedures carry out a number of different tasks to prepare the data for loading into the end system.

I want the query to carry out a wildcard search on the rows in the grades table. So for example for employees whose grades are in the table

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   Employee_ID,             
FROM
   @tmp_vo_hr_acp_staff v   
INNER JOIN
    hr_grades g ON v.hr_grade LIKE g.HR_Grade + '%' -- wildcard search
```

The reason for the wildcard is that the hr_grades can be like AC04(1) , AC04(2) etc.

This works fine. However I am struggling to get the reverse of this working.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       Employee_ID,             
    FROM
       @tmp_vo_hr_acp_staff v   
    INNER JOIN
        hr_grades g ON v.hr_grade NOT LIKE g.HR_Grade + '%'
```

Any ideas how I could get this to wildcard search to work on a NOT LIKE condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As almost always in SQL, there are some ways to do it:

```
-- 1. using outer join where the outer table don't match
SELECT DISTINCT Employee_ID
FROM @tmp_vo_hr_acp_staff v
LEFT JOIN hr_grades g ON (v.hr_grade LIKE g.HR_Grade + '%') -- wildcard search
WHERE g.id IS NULL -- use any non nullable column from hr_grades here

-- 2. using EXISTS for set difference
SELECT DISTINCT Employee_ID
FROM @tmp_vo_hr_acp_staff v
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 'x' FROM hr_grades g WHERE v.hr_grade LIKE g.HR_Grade + '%'
)

-- 3. using the less popular ANY operator for set difference
SELECT DISTINCT Employee_ID
FROM @tmp_vo_hr_acp_staff v
WHERE NOT v.hr_grade LIKE ANY (
    SELECT g.HR_Grade + '%' FROM hr_grades g
)
```

Personally, I don't like using joins for filtering, so I would probably use option 2. If `hr_grades` is a much smaller than `@tmp_vo_hr_acp_staff`, though, you can benefit from using the option 3 (as the set can be determined beforehand and than cached with a single read operation).

Comment: Went with option 2. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Change it to

```
ON NOT (v.hr_grade LIKE g.HR_Grade + '%' )
```

**EDIT:**

Removed the `ON` inside the brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I cannot seem to get that to work. Do you mean: -  FROM
  tmp_vo_hr_acp_staff v 
 INNER JOIN
  uol_acp_prof_grades g ON NOT (ON v.hr_grade LIKE g.HR_Grade + '%' )

Comment: Is the second `ON` supposed to be there?

Comment: @AndyB, sorry fixed that.

Comment: @astander No problem. That works fine if there is only one grade in the grades table. However soon as there is more than one then the query incorrectly returns a row. I guess because if the employee grade is for example AC04(1), then that is not like PR07 and therefore is returned?